# HTML - change image inside frame and keep frame size intact

Tags: html, css

My main goal is to have a simple frame (as you can see) with few text lines and images. The thing I want to do, is make this frame flexible. By that I mean - if I change picture inside of it (bigger -> smaller) the frame should change. It should stay fixed.

Online editor: `https://www.bootply.com/Y09Zn1wir3#`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="single-image-wrap">
    <div class="single-image">
      <div class="name">NAME</div>
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/14/07/basketball-147794_960_720.png" class="first-image">
      </div>
      <div class="extra-info">
        <div class="bottom-text">ABC</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="single-image-wrap">
    <div class="single-image">
      <div class="name">NAME</div>
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/14/07/basketball-147794_960_720.png" class="second-image">
      </div>
      <div class="extra-info">
        <div class="bottom-text">ABC</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.single-image{
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    float: right;
}


.name{
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: black;
    height: 75px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.img-wrap{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.first-image{
    width: 200px;
}

.second-image{
    width: 150px;
}

.extra-info{
    border-top: 1px solid orange;
}

.bottom-text{
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```

I tried to add height property to such as:

.single-image{
    ...
    height: 405px;
}

Result: `https://www.codeply.com/go/2s2hH3nbju`

But it doesn't look correct, as bottom text floats somewhere up.
I need a solution for different type of image sizes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `height` of `.img-wrap`, too.

```
.single-image{
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
  float: right;
  height: 405px;
}

.img-wrap{
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  height:250px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this new line in your css code.

```
.img-wrap{
  min-height: 275px;
}
```

it will looks like this

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm3gx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using **flex**

```css
.single-image{
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.name{
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: black;
    height: 75px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.img-wrap{
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.first-image{
    width: 200px;
}

.second-image{
    width: 150px;
}

.extra-info{
    border-top: 1px solid orange;
    align-self: bottom;
}

.bottom-text{
    padding-top: 15px;
    height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}            

.images-wrap{
display: flex;
}

.single-image-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="row images-wrap">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="single-image-wrap">
    <div class="single-image">
      <div class="name">NAME</div>
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/14/07/basketball-147794_960_720.png" class="first-image">
      </div>
      <div class="extra-info">
        <div class="bottom-text">ABC</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="single-image-wrap">
    <div class="single-image">
      <div class="name">NAME</div>
      <div class="img-wrap">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/12/14/07/basketball-147794_960_720.png" class="second-image">
      </div>
      <div class="extra-info">
        <div class="bottom-text">ABC</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
```